# Question with $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-f'(a)}{h}$

Tags: limits

I want to find out the flaw in this solution to the limit
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-f'(a)}{h}.$$
The numerator is
\begin{align*}
& \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-f'(a)
\\ & =\frac{f(a+h)-f(a+\frac{h}{2})+f(a+\frac{h}{2})-f(a)}{h}-f'(a)
\\ & =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f(a+h)-f(a+h/2)}{h/2}+\frac{f(a+h/2)-f(a)}{h/2}\right)-f'(a)
\\ & =\frac{1}{2}(f'(a+h/2)+f'(a))-f'(a)
\\ & =\frac{1}{2}(f'(a+h/2)-f'(a)).
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-f'(a)}{h} & = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}(f'(a+h/2)-f'(a))}{h}
\\ & =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{4}\frac{f'(a+h/2)-f'(a)}{h/2}
=\frac{1}{4}f''(a).
\end{align*}

Comment: Is it always valid to introduce limit inside limit?

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac hh &= 1\\
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\lim_{k\to 0}k}{h} &= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{0}{h} = 0
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think $$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a+h/2)}{h/2}=f'(a+h/2)$$ or $$\frac{f(a+h/2)-f(a)}{h/2} = f'(a)?$$ There's no reason to be like that.